# Dynamically adding divs causes weird style-sharing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having an annoying problem when dynamically adding divs to an existing div. I tried using the `appendChild` function, and also jQuery's append function; both give the same result. You can see the problem on this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/debu/5b3Qr/

If you press the 'add stuff' button, it will add several divs created dynamically. Inside the for-loop it creates a div, then adds two text-containing divs to that, before appending it to the "mainDiv". Then outside the for-loop, I create two further divs; one of them has a style applied to it which has its background-color set to a light orange.

The problem is, that the divs created in the for-loop seem to inherit this orange background colour, even though .. well, even though the element with that background is added *after* them. And it's not like the paragraph that comes after the orange-background div inherits the orange; it stays as it should, white.

I've played a lot with this and found no way to solve it. Any ideas?

Cheers,

debu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you were having issues with the divs (of class `compHolder`) you're adding that have `float:left` applied.
You need to clear `popupHeader3` with `clear:both;` to stop the header's background affecting those 3 divs before it from acting strangely.

Like so:

```
.popupHeader3 {
    background-color: #FFBA9B;
    margin-top:1px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "ProximaNova";
    font-size: 18px;
    clear:both;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/zyZ7Z/

Comment: Oh sweet, thanks so much! So what exactly is the clear style doing?